# Launch program after inactivity

Tags: applescript, launchd, screensaver, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automatically launch an application whenever the Mac goes idle?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39085/how-can-i-automatically-launch-an-application-whenever-the-mac-goes-idle)

I'd like to launch an AppleScript/ App after 30 minutes of system inactivity. e.g. no cursor movement or keyboard input?

Comment: What qualifies as inactivity? There are background processes running all the time on OS X.

Comment: Clarified inactivity to be no mouse or keyboard input.